# Detect rechanged options in select box jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have an edit form that contains multiple select fields with selected options. Is there any way for detect rechanged (reselected)options with jquery?

(I want to show a value when an select box is rechanged in edit)

Edit:
In the edit form I have select boxes that have already 'change' status. I want to know when select boxes rechanged:

```
<select multiple='multiple' id='select1'>
  <option selected="selected">option1</option>
  <option>option2</option>
  <option>option3</option>
</select>
<select multiple='multiple' id='select2'>
  <option selected="selected">option3</option>
  <option>option4</option>
  <option>option5</option>
</select>
```

change() or onchange() could not be usable because inputs come with 'change' evet on document ready.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean you want to detect a changed selection, without the actual focus being lost (which fires the change event), then you need to add other events such as 'click, focusout, keypress' etc. to your event management as you deem needed.

```
$('#myselectboxid').on('change click keypress', function(){
  //do my thing here
});
```

You can even add custom events if you want - say you are making modifications (like a new selection) through code and want to fire those events.

If you simply want to group the selections, you can do that using a class selector or an element selector:

```
$('.myselectboxOneClass').on('change', function(){
      //do my thing here
});

$('select').on('change', function(){
      //do my thing here
});
```

OR use multiple

```
$('.myselectboxOneClass, #myotherSelectId, .mySelectBoxTwoClass').on('change', function(){
      //do my thing here
});
```

From your edit: working example

http://jsfiddle.net/vhy7w/

Updated:  to show initially selected, just add a trigger of the change on startup :)
http://jsfiddle.net/vhy7w/1/

Comment: I am working on system that uses jquery 1.5. on('change click keypress', function(){}) not working on 1.5 --> http://jsfiddle.net/vhy7w/2/

Comment: change "on" to "delegate" for 1.5, the syntax is a bit different but the concept is the same.

Answer (score 1):

Won't something like this do it:

```
$('select').on('change', function () {
    // the select's option has changed
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you do add a class attribute to your select like that:

```
<select class='noticeable'>...</select>
```

And in your jQuery Code you add:

```
$('.noticeable').on('change',function(){
     //set some notification
});
```

By adding the class attribute you can "choose" on which select you want to do that notification. Otherwise if you would choose only `$('select')` the notification-Action would be performed on every select tag.